# Rails - Specifiy Root Path w/ Custom URL: '/dashboard'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

How do I make this root path go to: '/dashboard' instead of just http://example.com?

```
root :to => 'dashboard#index', :constraints => lambda{|req| !req.session[:user_id].blank?}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can accomplish that with:

```
root :to => redirect('/dashboard')
match '/dashboard', :to => "dashboard#index",
  :constraints => lambda {|req| !req.session[:user_id].blank? }
```